# Identify custom errors generated by a dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

When you add a reference to a dll and call its methods, if you enclose the code that calls a method in the dll with try catch statements, can you identify any custom errors the method in the dll might throw:

```
try
{
somedll.Product = new somedll.Product(1234, "Big, green product");
}
catch(
```

If I write the code above, Intellisense will show a long list of potential exceptions starting with AbandondedMutexException and ending with WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException

I read that it is bad practice to just catch exceptions generally using

```
catch(Exception ex)
```

Is there a way of telling which exceptions in the long list of exceptions are custom exceptions created by whoever wrote the dll?

Comment: This is info that you'll need to find in the documentation you got for using the DLL.  If it is lacking then you'll need help from the owner of the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround specific to your scenario would be to use all exceptions from the `System.Threading` namespace, as it seems that those 2 specific ones belong to it. Check the [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.aspx).

Comment: I wasn't referring to those exceptions specifically ... just that Intellisense shows a huge list from A to Z (well, A to W) of potential exceptions. I just want to know if somewhere in that list is a, for example, 'ProductIDAlreadyUsedException' being thrown. How can I tell which errors in the list are custom errors written by the author of the dll as opposed to errors which are part of the .net framework?